# Does $\lim_{x \searrow 0} \frac{\int_{x^4}^{2x^4} f(y) \ dy}{x^4}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, analysis

I have problems with this exercise: Let $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Does $$
\lim_{x \searrow 0} \frac{\int_{x^4}^{2x^4} f(y) \ dy}{x^4}
$$
exist? If so determine the limits value.
I actually have no idea how to approach this. Any help is appreciated. I think I am supposed to use the special case of the mean value theorem that states $\exists \xi \in [a, b]: f(\xi)(b-a) = \int_a^b f(y) \ dy$. But since $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary real numbers I cannot use the theorem right away. Correct? What can I say about the integral limits $x^4$ and $2x^4$? Or is this even important? Because otherwise I could just say
$$
\lim_{x \searrow 0} \frac{\int_{x^4}^{2x^4} f(y) \ dy}{x^4} = \lim_{x \searrow 0} f(\xi)(2x^4-x^4)\frac{1}{x^4} = f(\xi)
$$
for some $\xi \in [a, b]$?

Comment: U can use l'Hôpital rule, and derivate and it's easy calculate.

Comment: Your approach should work once you consider that $\xi$ depends on $x$... What happens to $\xi$ once $x$ goes to zero?

Comment: @soph6626 Do you mean $\xi$ depends on $x$ because the integral limits $x^4$ and $2x^4$ change as $x$ changes and $\xi \in [x^4, 2x^4]$? So as $x \to 0$ $\xi$ should also become 0 shouldn't it?

Comment: @FelixGervasi exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using what you were doing, let $x_{n}$ be a sequence that converges to $0$ from above. For every interval $I_{n} = (x_{n}^{4}, 2x^{4}_{n})$, there is a $\xi_{n} \in I_{n}$ such that the conditions of the mean value theorem hold. Note that $x_{n}^{4} \leq \xi_{n} \leq 2x_{n}^{4}$ so $\xi_{n} \to 0$ by the squeeze theorem. Let
$$g(x) = \frac{\int_{x^{4}}^{2x^{4}}f(y) \ dy}{x^{4}}$$
Then,
$$g(x_{n}) = \frac{\int_{x_{n}^{4}}^{2x_{n}^{4}}f(y) \ dy}{x_{n}^{4}} = \frac{f(\xi_{n})(2x_{n}^{4} - x_{n}^{4})}{x_{n}^{4}} = f(\xi_{n})$$
Then, $g(x_{n}) \to f(0)$ as $f(\xi_{n}) \to f(0)$ by the continuity of $f$. It follows that $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}g(x) = f(0)$.

Comment: Okay this actually makes so much sense to me. Thank you! Just a quick question about the notation. You denote $I_n = (x_n^4, 2x_n^4)$ as an open interval but mustn't the interval be compact if we want to apply the mean value theorem or does this actually not matter? @conan

Comment: The theorem is stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals). As $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$, it is continuous in $[x_{n}^{4}, 2x_{n}^{4}]$, and so there is a $\xi_{n} \in I_{n}$, the interior. @FelixGervasi

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Your notations are not good ($x\to 0^+$, however $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$...) Let suppose that $0\in [a,b)$ (I let you fix this problem).
Let $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\,\mathrm d t$. Then $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x^4}\int_{x^4}^{2x^4}f(t)\,\mathrm d t=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{F(2x^4)-F(x^4)}{x^4}=\lim_{u\to 0^+}\frac{F(2u)-F(u)}{u}=...$$

I let you conclude.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Still trying to figure it out but is it correct that you let $x$ tend to $0^+$ after you substituted for $u$ or did you mean $u \to 0^+$?

Comment: Yes of course, $u\to 0^+$